# XIB view has larger bound values and doesn't fit the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a XIB view.

When i added it to my view, i want the width and height to fit the iOS device.

However, it doesn't fit.

If i use autolayout it would fit the screen. But how do i use it ?

In the code example below, it takes the `Bounds` of the XIB file. Therefore it doesn't fit the view. How can i solve this?

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        self.myView=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

        self.bounds=self.myView.bounds;

        [self addSubview:self.myView];

    }

    return self;

}
```

Comment: `self.myView.bounds = self.bounds;`?

Comment: are you using auto-layout in the app? At minimum specify the auto-resizing rules

Comment: Yes i am using auto layout in the app. How to use auto-resizing rules  on the XIB ?

Comment: are you sure initWithFrame is being called in this case? I mean, when you instantiate view from xib, this method may not be called. try to set a breakpoint. if you discover it's not getting called, then try to make all stuff inside initWithCoder method

Comment: it passes through `initWithFrame `. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your view, then

```
    [_subview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_contentView addSubview:_subview];
    [self activateConstraintsForView:_subview respectToParentView:_contentView];
```

Use this function :

```
- (void)activateConstraintsForView:(UIView *)view respectToParentView:(UIView *)parentView
{

    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:parentView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:parentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:parentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:parentView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:topConstraint, leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, rightConstraint, nil]] ;
 }
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: how can i get it to load 1/2 the height of the view?

Comment: If you want to do so, replace 'bottomConstraint' in above answer with 'heightConstraint'.

    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:parentView.frame.size.height/2];

Answer (score 0):

In your initWithFrame method add this at the end:

```
[self setConstraintsOfView:self.myView withRespectToParentView:self];
```

And add the method below at the end of your class:

```
-(void)setConstraintsOfView:(UIView *)subView withRespectToParentView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"subView":subView};

    NSDictionary *metrics =@{@"offset":@0};

    NSArray *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-offset-[subView]-offset-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-offset-[subView]-offset-|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:metrics
                                                                         views:viewsDictionary];

    [parentView addConstraints:heightConstraint];

    [parentView addConstraints:widthConstraint];
}
```

VFL is much easier than setting each constraints. This method sets the  top, bottom, leading and trailing space = 0 of subview with respect to superview.

I think you want to achieve this though:
https://github.com/PrajeetShrestha/ConstraintTest